# Tracking bar progress based on tracking updates

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Out for delivery [date] => 07/06/2022 [time] => 10:30:12 AM ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Consolidation arrived at gateway [date] => 07/06/2022 [time] => 8:00:07 AM ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Departed sort facility [date] => 07/06/2022 [time] => 6:30:07 AM ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Arrived at sort facility [date] => 07/06/2022 [time] => 12:15:05 AM ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Departed sort facility [date] => 06/06/2022 [time] => 10:00:06 PM ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Driver collected [date] => 06/06/2022 [time] => 4:45:07 PM ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Label created [date] => 06/06/2022 [time] => 12:52:27 PM ) )
```

I have a variable for the progress of a bar

```
$progress = '0.25';
```

I am trying to set the progress of the bar based on whether either of the below tracking updates is present in the array. Of course, because multiple of the IF statements could return TRUE because all of those tracking updates could be present in the array, the code is not setting $progress correctly. Any ideas on how to solve this so that the correct value is set for $progress?

```
    foreach($events as $item) {

if ($item->message == "POD"){
    $progress = '1';
}
if ($item->message == "Out for delivery"){
    $progress = '0.75';
}
if ($item->message == "Departed sort facility"){
    $progress = '0.5';
}
if ($item->message == "Driver collected"){
    $progress = '0.25';
}

}
```

Comment: _"the code is not setting $progress correctly"_ - and what would be "the" correct value, in your opinion? You are looping over multiple items here, all of which can have different messages. So what actual result are you expecting, for the given input data?

Comment: If "POD" is present in the array $progress should equal 1 regardless of whether "Driver collected" or any of the other values are also present. However, because Driver collected" is always present when "POD" is in the array progress is being set to 0.25

Comment: in the array dump you gave, there's no "POD" so $progress cant never be equal to 1 too.

Comment: @skytorner That's just an example

Comment: _"If "POD" is present in the array $progress should equal 1 regardless of whether "Driver collected" or any of the other values are also present."_ - so exit the loop via `break;` then, once you found `POD` ...? So that the value of `$progress` does not get overwritten by any subsequent items with a different message any more?

Answer (score 0):

If we could consider a 1-1 relation between each step and progress.
What about this:

```
$steps = [
    'Out for delivery',
    'Consolidation arrived at gateway',
    'Out for delivery',
    'Consolidation arrived at gateway',
    'Departed sort facility ',
    'Arrived at sort facility ',
    'Departed sort facility ',
    'Driver collected',
    'Label created',
];

$steps_count = 0;
foreach ($events as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->message, $steps)) {
        $steps_count++;
    }
}

$progress = $steps_count / count($steps);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a good solution however there can sometimes be more or less tracking updates so we do not actually know the maximum or minimum number of tracking updates in an array

Answer (score 0):

Exiting the loop via `break;` once a tracking update has been found works:

```
foreach($events as $item) {

if ($item->message == "POD"){
    $progress = '1';
    break;
}
if ($item->message == "Out for delivery"){
    $progress = '0.75';
    break;
}
if ($item->message == "Departed sort facility"){
    $progress = '0.5';
    break;
}
if ($item->message == "Driver collected"){
    $progress = '0.25';
    break;
}

}
```